# Result of SelfAdjointEigenSolver saved as member is reinitialized when in another scope

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to run a pca on an block of an eigen matrix.
The observation in the input matrix are in columns. 
I want to save the eigen vectors as a matrix for later use.
But the matrix (m_pcaCoefs) "gets reinitialized" when I use it in another scope, inside the class of course.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something on how eigen works !

```
class foo {
    public:
    using InputMatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic>;

        void computePca(InputMatrixType & inputMatrix)
        {
            // m_pcaCoefs is a private member of dense matrix type
            size_t start = 1;
            auto r = inputMatrix.rows();
            auto c = inputMatrix.cols(); 
            Eigen::Block<InputMatrixType>  inputBlock 
                  = inputMatrix.block( start, 0 ,r-start , c   );

            // center the data
            m_pixelValueMeans = inputBlock.rowwise().mean();
            inputBlock.colwise() -= m_pixelValueMeans;

            // inputBlock is a d by n, where d is the number of observation
            InputMatrixType cov = inputBlock * inputBlock.adjoint();
            cov = cov / (c - 1);
            Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<InputMatrixType> eig(cov);
            InputMatrixType m_pcaCoefs = eig.eigenvectors();
            // here m_pcaCoefs looks fine
            std::cout << m_pcaCoefs.size() << std::endl; // output: 9  
        }

        void print()
        {
            std::cout << m_pcaCoefs.size() << std::endl; // output: 0
        }
    protected:
       InputMatrixType m_pcaCoefs;
}


int main()
{
    foo test;
    test.computePca(someMatrix); // outputs 9
    test.print() // output 0
}
```

Any clue how to get the eigenvectors to be copied to m_pcaCoefs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputMatrixType m_pcaCoefs = eig.eigenvectors();
```

this is not what you're thinking which is a member of your class.

you should just use:

```
m_pcaCoefs = eig.eigenvectors(); // use member m_pcaCoefs
```

Comment: m_pcaCoefs is a member variable, so declared in the class. Does it change anything to your answer ?

Comment: Thanks! Can't I just copy the eigenvectors() result data ? I thought that the `=` sign means copy for eigen...

Comment: That's totally implementation-specific. whatever you choose to do with `eigenvectors()` is up to you.

Comment: I edited the question to make sure that my problem is clear !

Comment: oh sorry, just noticed the typo... Thanks a lot !